# Getting error while running lerna bootstrap in Node 13

Tags: lerna

In Node 13 when I run `lerna bootstrap` I get this error:

```
lerna success Bootstrapped 10 packages
/Users/anatoliyzaslavskiy/.nvm/versions/node/v13.2.0/bin/node[97953]: ../src/signal_wrap.cc:159:void node::DecreaseSignalHandlerCount(int): Assertion `(new_handler_count) >= (0)' failed.
 1: 0x100081675 node::Abort() [/Users/anatoliyzaslavskiy/.nvm/versions/node/v13.2.0/bin/node]
 2: 0x10008141d node::AppendExceptionLine(node::Environment*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>, node::ErrorHandlingMode) [/Users/anatoliyzaslavskiy/.nvm/versions/node/v13.2.0/bin/node]
 3: 0x1000f5f0d node::DecreaseSignalHandlerCount(int) [/Users/anatoliyzaslavskiy/.nvm/versions/node/v13.2.0/bin/node]
 4: 0x1000f6685 node::(anonymous namespace)::SignalWrap::Close(v8::Local<v8::Value>) [/Users/anatoliyzaslavskiy/.nvm/versions/node/v13.2.0/bin/node]
 5: 0x10003a81e node::Environment::CleanupHandles() [/Users/anatoliyzaslavskiy/.nvm/versions/node/v13.2.0/bin/node]
 6: 0x10003a9d6 node::Environment::RunCleanup() [/Users/anatoliyzaslavskiy/.nvm/versions/node/v13.2.0/bin/node]
 7: 0x1000b3dd0 node::NodeMainInstance::Run() [/Users/anatoliyzaslavskiy/.nvm/versions/node/v13.2.0/bin/node]
 8: 0x10005da91 node::Start(int, char**) [/Users/anatoliyzaslavskiy/.nvm/versions/node/v13.2.0/bin/node]
 9: 0x7fff6fcb22e5 start [/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib]
error Command failed with signal "SIGABRT".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

But when I switch to version `12.13.1` runs without an error

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on this GH issue: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2373, updating from node `13.2.x` to node `13.3.x` solves this `lerna bootstrap` problem.